# How to export PNG without background using Python

Tags: qgis, python, arcgis-pro

I am trying to take sea level change PNGs outputted from a QGIS plugin and add these to a globe map in ArcGIS Pro. I am then georefencing these PNGs to line up with earth. The problem I am running into is that these output PNGs have white margins that then do not look good when on a globe in ArcGIS Pro. I think if I can get these exported from QGIS plugin without margins I should be good. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the NoData value already set? If not then you could Set Raster Properties in ArcGIS Pro  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/set-raster-properties.htm; That's an all-or-nothing option, it will set all white pixels transparent. If that's not suitable Clip Management to a polygon of the raster data area https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm you can use an irregular polygon and Spatial Analyst is not required.